# AWS 504 gateway timeout - early response from express middleware

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I see a 504 gateway timeout when running my service on AWS. Per my service logs, looks like the middleware returned early with a blank response, but the request to the 3rdPartyService did succeed. I am unable to reproduce this issue locally.

Here are the details: 
MyService <---> 3rdPartyService 
 
3rdPartyService takes over 2 min to respond, but does succeed ultimately.

MyService is using express on nodeJS, and is deployed using a docker container onto AWS. MyService is set to timeout well after the AWS ELB timeout which is set to 5 min.

Per the log snippet below, see line #16, where the blank response with status 200 is returned. And the 3rdPartyService request succeeding in the very last line.
MyService log snippet:

```
    {"name":"adapters/demo_adapter","hostname":"4658d629c774","pid":19,"level":30,"status":"PENDING","msg":"","time":"2016-09-19T21:10:09.973Z","v":0}
    {"name":"adapters/demo_adapter","hostname":"4658d629c774","pid":19,"level":30,"msg":"retrying function getLocation in 5000 ms : attempts: 1","time":"2016-09-19T21:10:09.975Z","v":0}
    {"name":"adapters/demo_adapter","hostname":"4658d629c774","pid":19,"level":30,"serviceRequestId":"da7fae85-f624-4338-adbe-4fc8674cd1","msg":"","time":"2016-09-19T21:10:46.037Z","v":0}
    {"name":"adapters/demo_adapter","hostname":"4658d629c774","pid":19,"level":30,"status":"PENDING","msg":"","time":"2016-09-19T21:10:48.354Z","v":0}
    {"name":"adapters/demo_adapter","hostname":"4658d629c774","pid":19,"level":30,"msg":"retrying function getLocation in 5000 ms : attempts: 2","time":"2016-09-19T21:10:48.354Z","v":0}
    {"name":"adapters/demo_adapter","hostname":"4658d629c774","pid":19,"level":30,"serviceRequestId":"da7fae85-f624-4338-adbe-4fc8674cd1","msg":"","time":"2016-09-19T21:10:56.424Z","v":0}
    {"name":"adapters/demo_adapter","hostname":"4658d629c774","pid":19,"level":30,"status":"PENDING","msg":"","time":"2016-09-19T21:11:00.365Z","v":0}
    {"name":"adapters/demo_adapter","hostname":"4658d629c774","pid":19,"level":30,"msg":"retrying function getLocation in 5000 ms : attempts: 3","time":"2016-09-19T21:11:00.365Z","v":0}
    {"name":"adapters/demo_adapter","hostname":"4658d629c774","pid":19,"level":30,"serviceRequestId":"da7fae85-f624-4338-adbe-4fc8674cd1","msg":"","time":"2016-09-19T21:11:07.049Z","v":0}
    {"name":"adapters/demo_adapter","hostname":"4658d629c774","pid":19,"level":30,"status":"PENDING","msg":"","time":"2016-09-19T21:11:08.508Z","v":0}
    {"name":"adapters/demo_adapter","hostname":"4658d629c774","pid":19,"level":30,"msg":"retrying function getLocation in 5000 ms : attempts: 4","time":"2016-09-19T21:11:08.509Z","v":0}
    {"name":"adapters/demo_adapter","hostname":"4658d629c774","pid":19,"level":30,"serviceRequestId":"da7fae85-f624-4338-adbe-4fc8674cd1","msg":"","time":"2016-09-19T21:11:17.422Z","v":0}
    {"name":"adapters/demo_adapter","hostname":"4658d629c774","pid":19,"level":30,"status":"PENDING","msg":"","time":"2016-09-19T21:11:19.128Z","v":0}
    {"name":"adapters/demo_adapter","hostname":"4658d629c774","pid":19,"level":30,"msg":"retrying function getLocation in 5000 ms : attempts: 5","time":"2016-09-19T21:11:19.129Z","v":0}

    {"name":"myservice-api","hostname":"4658d629c774","pid":19,"level":30,"method":"GET","url":"/path/b7446b06-7ac6-40c1-94cd-08fbade4387f/location","status":200,"userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.116 Safari/537.36","version":"1.0","ipAddress":"XX.XX.XX.XX","time":129711.250805,"msg":"","v":0}

    {"name":"adapters/demo_adapter","hostname":"4658d629c774","pid":19,"level":30,"serviceRequestId":"da7fae85-f624-4338-adbe-4fc8674cd1","msg":"","time":"2016-09-19T21:11:26.294Z","v":0}
    {"name":"adapters/demo_adapter","hostname":"4658d629c774","pid":19,"level":30,"status":"PENDING","msg":"","time":"2016-09-19T21:11:27.995Z","v":0}
    {"name":"adapters/demo_adapter","hostname":"4658d629c774","pid":19,"level":30,"msg":"retrying function getLocation in 5000 ms : attempts: 6","time":"2016-09-19T21:11:27.996Z","v":0}
    {"name":"adapters/demo_adapter","hostname":"4658d629c774","pid":19,"level":30,"serviceRequestId":"da7fae85-f624-4338-adbe-4fc8674cd1","msg":"","time":"2016-09-19T21:11:36.641Z","v":0}

    {"name":"adapters/demo_adapter","hostname":"4658d629c774","pid":19,"level":30,"coord":{"lat":37.39948777777778,"lon":-102.045195},"status":"SUCCESS","msg":"","time":"2016-09-19T21:11:39.416Z","v":0}
```